# Issues with the DocuSign quickstart tool's produced Java Spring Boot example (OAuth2 client authorization code grant) app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi

Thanks for reading my question.
I am trying to build an OAuth2 client app (Authorization code grant type) integrating with DocuSign. I followed the documentation and the recommended [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) way of getting started with the Spring Boot Java code, firstly I couldn't understand why there are 2 src folders in the produced project.

Other than this, the quickstart tool says to follow the README.md for further instructions but unfortunately, the project generated like above doesn't come with any README file. I followed the [Github](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java) page of DocuSign java examples and tried to run the app in IntelliJ Ultimate but **I am facing errors viz. "java: package com.docusign.common does not exist"**, "com.docusign.core.model.manifestModels does not exist" I tried to invalidate cache and re-build and re-import the dependencies multiple times but no help.

I am a bit perplexed by why there are some classes of the external src folder (like OSDetector etc) being used in the inner src folder, and is it really a Spring Boot project or Spring MVC or kind of in between?

I would like to add for any Developer Advocate reading from DocuSign, instead of loading the examples with a number of libraries and making them complex try to showcase examples (maybe a few) just with your library/ SDK and minimum other dependencies so as we can see your SDK in action in isolation. Definitely, we will add to it as we will build a proper integration.

Thanks again!! :)

**EDIT - 10/04/22**

As advised I tried to generate the project using quick-start with the extreme right OAuth grant type option (Multiple code examples, ACG, and JWT grant) the project is coming up with one main "src" folder and separate projects for ACG and JWT in folders named as "Quick_ACG" and "JWT Console App". I deleted the "Quick_ACG" and "JWT Console App" folders just to see if they are anywhere connected with the main app and as anticipated doesn't look like they are. After configuring and running the main project same is running fine, and I can use it as a starter code for prospective integration.

I tried to generate an authorization-code-grant flow project using quick-start, but I can't run the same, adding a picture depicting both scenarios here (ACG on left and full app on right).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqEcf.jpg)

Rest I am still unclear why so many "src" folders are there as you can see in the above image for the ACG type project and here as well ([full project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCJDw.png)), and moreover, classes from the inner "src" folder are referring to classes in outer src folder for example `OSDetector`

Comment: There are 3 options for Java, I understand you picked the right-most (full), can you try one of the other 2?

Comment: @InbarGazit thanks for the swift reply, actually I picked the middle one only "Authorization code grant embedded signing example", tried it again just now as well it's the same 2 src folders.

Comment: can you try the right-most option?

Comment: UPDATE: This is fixed now, please try again

Comment: Thanks for working to resolve my problem, I have edited the question depicting the current state. I couldn't get the authorization grant flow OAuth client (Java Spring) working but at least the app depicting all APIs ( generated using extreme right side grant type) is functioning.

Comment: Did you start from scratch and download the middle project again? as I said here, we fixed the code and it should work now.

Comment: Please do everything from scratch again, don't use the older code/ZIP file

Comment: Yeah, I am doing everything from scratch, got the new project generated today only, not referring to any older code or zip files. Facing errors as depicted in a picture I have added in the 10/04/22 edit above (where I am showing App class of ACG and full project side by side), the entry point class com.docusign.App is using OSDetector class which is located in the outer src folder, I never saw something like this ever earlier in any Java project. I am in for learning something new, but not getting.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse to compile this?

Comment: I try this from commandline and it works ok

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate for compiling and running.

Comment: Let me generate the project again and try running it using a different IDE or maybe like you are doing from the command line. Thanks for replying, have a blessed day!

Comment: I run mvn package  and then I run java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar target\code-examples-java-acg-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Yes, the way you mentioned is working, thanks Inbar :)

Comment: Looks like there is some problem with IntelliJ's embedded maven plugin, I should have tried maven itself directly from the command line, well learn and live :)

Comment: Thanks, we'll check InteliJ and see if we can fix

Comment: Hey, @InbarGazit all the sample apps shown on https://developers.docusign.com/sample-apps/ are written in different languages but Java, could you please guide me to some Java sample apps?

Comment: We don't have one yet, but hope to have one soon. Sorry about that.

Comment: Appreciate your response, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 10/3/2022** - We have made a fix available, please try again and it should work properly.

We have identified a regression bug in the "Authorization code grant embedded signing example" (middle option) of the Java quickstart. You can try the right-most (full) option for now. We'll fix it soon.
The full option includes all code examples as well as both Auth Code Grant and JWT so should be good for now.